# Is there a system call in Linux to implement NAT ( port forwarding)?

Tags: linux, network-programming, udp, iptables

I know that this can be done in iptables and a bunch of other network utilities. Are there any system calls in Linux to do this? I am only interested in UDP port forwarding to another host.

My implemented function would look like:

```
    portForward(portNo, toHost, toPort);
```

This function will use the Linux system calls. Issues like whether the portNo is in use can be detected using Linux system calls which I am aware of. I need system calls to port forward. Yes, there will be other issues that will have to be dealt with. If you can shed some light on them too, it will help.

Keep alives and other such issues are not part of the scope of this question.

Comment: No, there isn't. You can call iptables, or write a program do what iptables do, or use UDP socket to forward packets. There isn't a simple solution. And I'm closing the question because it is too broad.

Comment: @ZangMingJie "use UDP socket to forward packed" you mean read and write to forwarded host and port? That would not be port forwarding as I understand... would be inefficient.

Comment: why do you want a "system call" to do this?  what's wrong with iptables or userspace programs?

Comment: @SamMason I want to have some additional control over the NAT mapping at the application level.  iptables offers you plain vanilla mapping. userspace program may involve an additional socket IO which I want to avoid. iptables will need to examine the ip payload anyway... userspace program will repeat this. For a real-time application, I want to reduce the latency wherever possible.

Comment: what sort of control?  iptables gives a lot more control than your proposed `portForward` function, which gives basically no options!